# Failed to load gem within passenger app but gem loads in irb

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, passenger

I've deployed a few rails apps but just infrequently enough to feel like every time is my first time. This time I'm installing a sinatra app.

I'm using mod_passenger and I'm getting a problem with a missing gem. However it's there.

From the error in the browser I see:

```
no such file to load -- json (LoadError)
  ./application.rb:10:in `require'
  ./application.rb:10
  config.ru:1:in `require'
  config.ru:1
  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1
```

The top of the file looks like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'
require 'sequel'
require 'sinatra/sequel'
```

(there are comments above these lines, hence the line number differences)

When I open irb and try to require the gems it works:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'json'
=> true
```

Sadly, I'm using RHEL 6.2 which is different enough from Ubuntu that I'm a little uncomfortable. But based on my understanding this should work.

Any ideas on things I could look for to see what could cause my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure that passenger is running the same ruby version like irb?

Comment: Thanks! That was not the problem but it lead me right to it. :-) Something I did not know was that all modules must be mentioned in the Gemfile. 'json' and 'sqlite3' were not but once I added them, it started working. (well, it started giving me an error I could deal with)